# Strange output current waveform

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, inductor, current-measurement, piezo

I have another question regarding output voltage and current of the driver as continuation of my question @ [Inductance overheating](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258404/inductance-overheating?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
Voltage measured on the input of the piezo has a square wave shape on the positive part and sine wave form on the negative side. But the current shows very strange shape and frequency about 160 kHz instead of 80 kHz. Please, I need your help to understand the current shape reasons and to calculate the output power of the driver. It is very important for me. Thanks in advance.
[image]
[!The blue one is a voltage, and yellow is a current[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FaFz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FaFz.png)
Thanks @ Tony Stewart, next week I will receive inductances from Coilcraft with composite cores and can try them out.

Comment: hmm not TOKO?  Create test circuit with high resistive current and ensure your measurement methods give textbook squarewave waveforms, no ringing.  since we cannot verify what you are doing.

Comment: @TonyStewart: What do you mean TOKO? I use inductancies from TOKO and temperature rises up to 145 degrees Celsius. And you are right, there is some gate ringing on the mosfet. Do you have any suggestions how to reduce that ringing and reactive power? I reduced resistance on the gate and I think it works better, but I am quite sure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Analyze all reactive elements and understand why ringing occurs. conductors, returns, ESL stray capacitance, loops on high I conductors, back EMF etc. Saturation on a 50mV current shunt is easy to monitor on magnetic parts

Comment: What Tony said, add your first order parasitics to your simulation and that ringing should show up.